# Batch script logic

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for one logic to implement in batch script. Below are my cases

I have receiving file name in the `.eml_body`, but name of the file will be different when I execute my code, I have scheduled a task  to execute the code every 5 minute and files will be generated.

For example, when I execute code first time files will be generated like `1000.eml_body` and second time when I execute file will be like `1001.eml_body`.
   Here I need to consider only the format of the file `.eml_body`, so if this format present in  mentioned directory I need to move other files present in that directory.
  I have written below code not it is giving error

```
set str=.eml_body
if exist "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\%str% goto Move
:Move D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\  * D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\bckup

pause
```

Comment: Perhaps `"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder" "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\bckup" /Mov /XF *.eml_body` will suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the label and it's content on a single line and you need to double quote paths always, especially the ones with whitespace and the goto is not needed here.

```
@echo off
set "str=.eml_body"
if exist "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\%str%" (
    move "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\*" "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\bckup"
)
pause
```

If however your intention was to move all `.eml_body` files then I suppose you just wanted to do this:

```
move "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\*.eml_body" "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\bckup" /Y
```

**Edit** Based on your now more clear comment, this is what you want.

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\New folder\*") do if /i not "%%~xi"==".eml_body" if not "%%~i"=="%~nx0" move "%%~i" "D:\Cash_Apps_New\OutputFolder\bckup\%%~nxi"
```

Comment: Actually I not moving only .eml_body file, I am checking whether .eml_body is present in the location, if its present I am moving all files other than .eml_body present in that location

Comment: Do we have any other logic implement do this? the above solution which you proposed is not working

Comment: ok, if the question was more clear I would have known that from the beginning. So you just want `.eml_body` in the folder, anything else should move out? Also are the files exactly like that, no other extensions?